# Use enum that implements interface as parameter as key in EnumMap

Tags: java, enum-map

I want to have a family of child classes that extend BaseClass, which has in turn a EnumMap defined. Depending on the IDE I plug this code in. It tells me that the Constructor

```
EnumMap<B, Integer>()
```

is not defined, respectively B is not within the specified bounds.

```
interface A {}
enum B implements A {hello, world}

abstract class BaseClass {
    protected EnumMap<? extends A, Integer> baseMap;
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    public ChildClass () {
        baseMap = new EnumMap<B,Integer>();
    }
}
```

E.g. the third last line gives me troubles. I don't see what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EnumMap` takes the `enum` in [the constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Class)):

```
baseMap = new EnumMap<B,Integer>(B.class);
```

And as we're in a [post Java 7 world](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html)

```
baseMap = new EnumMap<>(B.class);
```

---

I would suggest using a `Map` in the declaration - program to the `interface`:

```
protected Map<? extends A, Integer> baseMap;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked partially :) Two questions: 1.) How would I put an object into the map now, `baseMap.put(B.hello, 10);` gives me a weird error message... 2.) Why do suggest map over EnumMap in this example, especially as I already know that I want to use enum type keys?

Comment: For 2) becuase they're not an `enum`, they are an `A` - this is an `interface` and there is no reason something else could not implement it. For 1) due to [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19739576/2071828) you can not call method that takes `? extends` as an argument - you would need to use `Map<A, Integer>` if you want to `put()`.

Comment: @Felix.C given the quantity of questions about co/contra-variance on SO, you are far from the only person to think so...

Comment: It still struggle :( I use `protected Map<A, Integer> baseMap;` with `new EnumMap<B,Integer>(B.class);`. I mean B is an A and EnumMap is a map, why does this not work?

Comment: Because, as you know `A` is not an `Enum` and a `Map<A, Integer>` is not the same as a `Map<B, Integer>`...